# Searching multiple strings using like

Tags: kdb

How to use `like` for searching mulitiple strings ?

```
q)\l sp.q

q)select from p where city like "lon*"
p | name  color weight city
--| -------------------------
p1| nut   red   12     london
p4| screw red   14     london
p6| cog   red   19     london
```

I want to search the `city` either starting with "lon" or "par", `/:` gives `type` error.

```
q)select from p where city like/: ("lon*";"par*")
'type
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `any` when searching for multiple strings.

```
q)select from p where any city like/: ("lon*";"par*")

p | name  color weight city
--| -------------------------
p1| nut   red   12     london
p2| bolt  green 17     paris
p4| screw red   14     london
p5| cam   blue  12     paris
p6| cog   red   19     london
```

When you search using the `/:` (each right ), it returns 2 vectors , one against the "lon*" search and another for "par*".

```
(0!p)[`city] like/: ("lon*";"par*")
(100101b;010010b)
```

using `any` does the ORing and returns a single vector.

```
any (0!p)[`city] like/: ("lon*";"par*")
110111b
```

Now getting the final result :

```
(0!p) where any (0!p)[`city] like/: ("lon*";"par*")
p  name  color weight city
----------------------------
p1 nut   red   12     london
p2 bolt  green 17     paris
p4 screw red   14     london
p5 cam   blue  12     paris
p6 cog   red   19     london
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, using `any` with `each-right` is the best approach here and the most legible.

An alternative (which can be useful in some scenarios and can be slightly more efficient for large vectors) involves making use of the built-in regex functionality as follows:

```
q)city:`london`london`newyork`paris
q)city like "[lp][oa][nr]*"
1101b
```

The caveat here being that it would also pick up `"lan*"`, `"lar*"`, `"por*"` and `"pan*"` but if it is known that those combinations are not possible then it's feasible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `any` to your where clause. Right now your `where` clause is resolving to 2 lists

```
q)city:`london`london`newyork`paris
q)city like/: ("lon*";"par*")
1100b
0001b
q)any city like/: ("lon*";"par*")
1101b
```

so...

```
select from p where any city like/: ("lon*";"par*")
```